# Change account login

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, login

Currently I am logging with launchpad,Lanchpad id logins with yahoo id, I want to change account login details and login directly through yahoo Id. How can I do this with  keeping same points and batches ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [your profile](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/54296/k-k-patel), click on the "My Logins" links above the about me. In the popup window, click on *Add more logins* and add Yahoo login from there. Yahoo is the fourth option from left to right.